# Bad:freezing app while using loop in kivy

Tags: python, firebase, python-requests, kivy, boxlayout

i have problem when i use loop in kivy app to show update value for loop, so when i run app and press toggle button to start showing last value of loop i program crash.
this is code:

*.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from random import randint


class ShowLoopValueInterface(BoxLayout):
    ToggleButton_label = StringProperty("normal")
    Label_text_value = StringProperty("normal")

    def togglebutton_on_state(self, widget):
        if widget.state == "down":
            self.ToggleButton_label = "down"
            # self.to_text_value()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.to_text_value, 0.5)
        else:
            self.ToggleButton_label = "normal"
    def to_text_value(self, _):
    # def to_text_value(self):
        while True:
            self.Label_text_value = str(randint(0, 100))


class ShowLoopValueApp(App):
    pass


ShowLoopValueApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
ShowLoopValueInterface:
<ShowLoopValueInterface>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    ToggleButton:
        text: root.ToggleButton_label
        on_state: root.togglebutton_on_state(self)
    Label:
        text: root.Label_text_value
```

Comment: Try using [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#module-kivy.clock) to update value.

Comment: You need to start an extra thread that runs the Loup, otherwise the program will run the Loup first until the Loup is finished.

Comment: @ApuCoder i use Clock but it give: TypeError: to_text_value() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (look post i update code) and thnks

Comment: @KamelMenazeli Clock-scheduled functions receive the time since they were called as an argument (which is the argument the error message is telling you about). Declare `def to_text_value(self, _):` instead to ignore this argument since you don't need it.

Comment: But you also need to get rid of the `while True:` loop in that function, the idea is you're using the kivy Clock instead of the while loop.

Comment: @inclement thank you man i use '''def to_text_value(self, _):''' and it work as i hope